# Image rollover using css background image

Tags: css, image, rollover

I have explored alternative methods for creating image rollover effects (both CSS & javascript). In the process I have encountered unexplained behavior using one particular CSS method:

```
.main-banner a#link1{
    background-image: url(images/yellow-button_03.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    width:310px;
    height:85px;
    top:190.2px;
    left:277px;
} 

.main-banner a:hover#link1{

    background-image: url(images/yellow-button-bright_03.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

This method creates a hotspot with background image. on mouse-over the image is replaced with a different colored button with the exact same dimensions.

On the first mouse-over there is an extremely slight flicker as the rollover image is initialized for the first time only. The event only occurs subsequent to the first cache of the stylesheet.

My question is as follows:

Given that the CSS is completely loaded why does this behavior occur?

The behavior would indicate that the css background rollover image is not loaded until the initial mouse-over event? However this is not the case.

Please do not provide an alternative solution for replicating rollover functionality. This is not the question.

I am only interested in understanding why there is a slight flicker upon first rollover. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.main-banner a#link1:hover{

    background-image: url(images/yellow-button-bright_03.png) no-repeat;

}
```

Generally pseudo classes written after selector, `a or a#link1` is selector  so you should write `a#link1:hover`

Checkout this http://jsfiddle.net/d5RpE/1/

@Tuanderful - exactly so in this condition we can use "image spriting", so that when first time :hover event will occur - image will not fluctuate

Comment: Using the above method, the fluctuation still occurs. I thank you for your response, however, the question remains unanswered. I am looking for a "why" not a "how".

Answer (score 0):

Although the CSS has completely loaded, I don't think all of the elements referenced in the CSS are loaded until needed. In other words, `yellow-button_03.png` is loaded to render the link when the page first loads, but i believe `yellow-button-bright_03.png` only loads after you hover over the link.

Comment: This was the first explanation that came to my mind. I would like to be sure that this explanation is 100% correct.

Comment: I verified this by using inspecting the element in Chrome. I do something similar on www.2uan.com; if you load the page and look at the Resources tab in the Developer Tools, under Frames > (2uan.com) > Images, on page load you'll see a `social.png` image loaded. Once you hover over the icons in the footer, you'll see the Images updated with `social-hover.png`. I'm not sure if its the best way to resolve the issue, but I will probably combine the `social` sprites with the `social-hover` sprites to load them all on page load and get rid of the flicker.